# How to draw arc under words (HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, utf-8

If I have a word encoded in UTF-8, how can I draw an arc under it?

For example, say I have a function that can do the above job: call it `arc()`. Now, `arc(ABCD)` should return the following example image:

[image: example output]

Although for practical application, it would be ideal if the output is not an image but UTF-8 encoded text perhaps. Is it possible to do this using HTML, CSS and/or JavaScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use an after element:

```css
.arc {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.arc:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% - 7px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height:10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<span class="arc">abcd</span>
```